# Detect row difference (view or model)?

Tags: django

I would like to display a list of publications on my website; however, I would also like to diaplay a header stating the year for each set of publications published on that particular year.

So I would like for my end result to be like this (my reputation is 1 :( I could not upload the image):

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10752936/Screen%20Shot%202013-06-21%20at%206.00.15%20PM.png

I have a table with three columns; `id (primary key), title (the title of the article), and date (the date of publications)`

In my template file; doing the following will print the header before every article:

```
{% for curr_pub in all_publications %}
    <h1>{{ curr_pub.date.year }}</h1>
    <li>{{ curr_pub.title }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I am passing `all_publications` ordered by `'-date'` which means that I can compare the **year** of the current row `curr_pub` with the previous one and check if it differs or not; and print (or not print) the header accordingly. It seems however, that I cannot do that in the template.

Since I am new to Django and Python, I wasn't sure what to do and this is where I need help; my thoughts were the following:

1) Add a function in the `model` (`def is_it_first_publication(self):`) that returns `true` or `false` - but I really wasn't able to do that :| - ...and I'm not sure if that is what I needed to do or not!

2) Second one is to do in in the `view`, and pass extra variable(s) to the template; here's an example (which works just fine for this case):

**In the view:**

```
def publications(request):
    all_publications = Publications.objects.order_by('-date')

    after_first_row_flag = False
    f_year = 'Null'
    list_of_ids_of_first_publications = []

    for curr_pub in all_publications:
        if after_first_row_flag:
            if curr_pub.date.year != f_year:
                list_of_ids_of_first_publications.append(curr_pub.id)
                f_year = curr_pub.date.year
        else:
            # The year of first (or earliest) publication has to be added
            #
            list_of_ids_of_first_publications.append(curr_pub.id)
            f_year = curr_pub.date.year
            after_first_row_flag = True

    template = loader.get_template('counters/publications.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'all_publications': all_publications,
        'list_of_first_publications': list_of_ids_of_first_publications,
    })

    return HttpResponse(template.render(context))
```

**In the template:**

```
    {% for curr_pub in all_publications %}
        {% if curr_pub.id in list_of_first_publications %}
            <h1> {{ curr_pub.date.year }} </h1>
        {% endif %}
        <li> Placeholder for [curr_pub.title] </li>
    {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `regroup` built in filter can do this for you without annotating your objects in the view.  As the documentation says, it's kind of complicated.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup

```
{% regroup all_publications by date.year as year_list %}
{% for year in year_list %}
  <h1>{{ year.grouper }}</h1>
  {% for publication in year.list %}
    <li>{{ publication.title }}</li>
  {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want the [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag;

```
{% regroup all_publications by date as publication_groups %}
<ul>
{% for publication_group in publication_groups %}
    <li>{{ publication_group.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for publication in publication_group.list %}
          <li>{{ publication.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Three answers suggesting regroup posted within a minute of each other.  Nice.

Comment: I'll upvote all and accept Peter's answer :) - since he did not forget the year `date.year` instead of `date` =P - So will the grouped subgroups be ordered as well (`-date`)?

Comment: If you look at the docs for the tag, it talks about the ordering of the groups: `Note that {% regroup %} does not order its input! Our example relies on the fact that the cities list was ordered by country in the first place`. So they aren't ordered by default, but if you have ordered them before applying the `regroup` they should be ok, otherwise there is an approach to reordering each subgroup

Comment: The `ifchanged` built in tag could also do this.  I am not sure offhand if there's much reason for choosing one over the other.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper: Thanks :) - I'll look into `ifchanged` too!

Comment: I did a little digging and found that it might have problems with the first year group - going from nothing to something may not count as a change.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the template tag [`regroup`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) could help.

Alternatively, you could do this grouping by year in the view function (will try to provide code later).